# Example of a probability theorem that requires axioms in addition to Kolmorogov's?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, soft-question

Probability theory, in it's more general form, is axiomatized by [Kolmorogov's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms):

### Kolmorogov's Probability Axioms

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a measure space.

The three axioms are:

1. **Positivity**: $E \in \mathcal{F} \implies P(E)\geq 0$
2. **Unit Measure of $\Omega$**: $P(\Omega)=1$
3. **$\sigma-$additivity**: Let $E_i$ be a countable sequence of disjoint events, then:
   $$P\left(\biguplus_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(E_i)$$

---

Now, all theorems in probability theory should be *consistent with* these axioms. However, it that doesn't imply that they should be *derivable from* these axioms.

My question relates to how much of probability theory we can reconstruct from just these axioms? Do we hit a theoretical wall that requires new axioms to allow for further theoretical development in a particular sub-field?

This may seem obvious to those who study this for a living, but as a practitioner (read: not a theoretician), it is not obvious if these axioms are sufficient to reconstruct modern probability theory without specialized axioms for particular sub-fields (e.g., stochastic processes, large deviations, random graphs, percolations, etc.).

I'm not saying that these sub-fields don't have their own definitions and concepts, a simple google search quickly shows this. I am asking the deeper question of whether these additional assumptions/axioms are more akin to "convenience axioms" (which are just re-casts/reformulations of pre-existing axioms in a new terminology for the sake of consistency) or are they truly independent of (meaning not derivative or equivalent to) the above axioms?

**In response to the close requests**

I see that some have voted to close because its not specific enough. I would like to get an answer to this, so I've given some thought about how to make this more specific. See my more restricted question below:

### Restricted/Revised Question

I will accept as an answer one of two things:

1. An example (read: one) of a theorem in probability that relies upon axioms in addition to those above.
2. An explanation as to why no such theorems exist.

Comment: Can you provide an example of theorem of prob.theory that is *consistent* with these axioms. but **not** *derivable* from them ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA if I could do that, then I wouldn't need to ask this question...the answer would be no.

Comment: The axioms you state seem not to deal with continuous probability (the kind in which a density function gets integrated over $E$ to define $P(E).$

Comment: @coffeemath if that is true, that means that a very large branch of probability theory is not based solely on these axioms. Perhaps I am not citing the most sophisticated formulation of these axioms? I was using Wolfram MathWorld.

Comment: If you drop your assumption that $S$ is either finite or countable, and throw in that it is a measure space with a measurable function $P$ defined on it, then I think your 4 axioms are the general ones. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms .

Comment: **These are not Kolmogorov axioms**. The page you copied this from restricts the setting to at most countable sample spaces. No such restriction is enforced in K axioms.

Comment: @Did coffeemath pointed this out as well. I didn't have time to revise before you posted your comment. I've taken your and coffeemath's comments to heart (as well as the close flags). I've added what I hope is the most general formulation and those that I hope can be attributed to K. Also, I made my question more specific so its less of a "discussion" and more answerable.

Comment: @Did also, since you are knowledgeable in this area, do you think you could shed light on this question? Many thanks!

Comment: @Did is my revised set of Axioms what are traditionally known as Kolmorogov's Axioms? I saw this page on Wolfram, but I didn't recognize the notation: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KolmogorovsAxioms.html. Again, any constructive input would be appreciated :-)

Comment: @Bey, after assuming that $(Ω, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a measure space, the only new thing you are adding is that the space has measure 1 (the other 2 are part of the definition of what it means to be a measure). Also, I don't know a single result in measure-theoretic probability theory that does not start with "let $(Ω,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space", or some variant (e.g. filtered probability space), just my 2¢.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I totally agree. My question is not if there are theorems that don't rely on the above axioms (I doubt there are), but if these axioms are *sufficient* for all theorems -- of course, I am almost sure ;-) that they are *necessary*.

Comment: I think I have a problem understanding the question. Maybe I don't even know what an axiom is. Why are we calling it an axiom, when we can always exhibit the ambient space, $\sigma$-algebra and probability measure if you forced us to? With this, not a single theorem I know 'assumes' any of your axioms: they are proven to have those properties. Is this more of a 'what would probability theory be, if $P$ was not a probability measure' question?

Comment: @CalvinKhor the above are referred to as the axioms of probability. They set the foundation for what is a valid probability measure. From this, you can prove a number of theorems about monotonicity, inclusion-exclusion, tail event probabilities, etc. They start from the assumption of a measureable space equipped with a non-negative measure, with total measure 1.

Comment: @CalvinKhor for example, measure theory allows a number of non-probability concepts: negative and complex measures, non-$\sigma$ additivity, etc. Its the particular mix of requirements that pick out which measures and measure spaces are valid.

Comment: Well, these 'axioms' have always been just the *definition* of a probability measure/probability space to me. When you ask if these axioms are "sufficient", do you mean that "Let $(Ω,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, and let $X$ be a random variable..." would count as a example that requires more 'axioms'? (I feel really dense asking these questions, sorry)

Comment: @CalvinKhor hmm...I guess that's a good point. In that case, what is an example of a theorem where we need to define things beyond a probability space?

Comment: How about any theorem relying on a filtered probability space? It is a 4-tuple $(Ω,\mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}, P)$ where for $s<t$, $\mathcal{F}_s⊂\mathcal{F}_t ⊂ \mathcal{F}$ are a collection of sub-$\sigma$-algebras which constitute the 'information knowable at time $t$'. Without it, there isn't a concept of time to go with your stochastic process e.g. random walk, brownian motion, martingale.

Comment: @CalvinKhor that sounds promising. It's definitely an extension to the above axioms...I'll take it if you can post it as an answer with a little more explanation of why its distinct from the usual probability space in K's axioms. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with collections of random variables indexed by time, we need more than just a probability space $(Ω, \mathcal{F},P)$ to capture the notion of 'information knowable at time $t$'. It is termed a [filtered probability space](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=filtered%20probability%20space&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), which is a 4-tuple $(Ω,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F_t})_{t\geq 0},P)$ where the new ingredient is a [filtration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtration_(mathematics)), i.e. a collection of sub-$\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F_t} ⊂ \mathcal{F}$ such that

$$ s<t \implies \mathcal{F_s} ⊂ \mathcal{F_t}$$

This normally comes with the concept of an [adapted stochastic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapted_process) $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ i.e. a collection of random variables where $X_t$ are $\mathcal{F_t}$-measurable.

Why do we want to have collections of $\sigma$-algebras? Well, it turns out that [conditional expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) (and thus, conditional probabilities) are most naturally expressed in terms of sub-$\sigma$-algebras. The game of guessing a result in the future based on information in the present is therefore easy to discuss in such a setting.

For example, the statement that your winnings $X_n$ from playing in a casino will on average decrease as you play, can be formalised as saying that $X_n$ forms a (discrete-time) [supermartingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)), i.e. if $k<n$, then

$$\Bbb E[X_n | \mathcal{F_k}] \leq X_k $$

For another example, the markov property is that
$$ P(X_t ∈ A|\mathcal{F_s}) =  P(X_t ∈ A|X_s)$$

A theorem that one soon encounters after these definitions is the [Optional Stopping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem). For a celebrated result that requires this framework, I refer you to
the [Black-Scholes Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model).